# How can I reference logo.png files with names in my React application and display them dynamically for the tech stack of my projects section?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, jsx

I'm working on a web development project where I have a list of projects, each with a title, description, and a technology stack. I want to display technology icons next to the names of the technologies used in each project's description. For example, if a project uses React, I want to display the React logo next to it.

To achieve this, I have individual image files for each technology logo, such as React.png, Nodejs.png, etc. I also have an array of technology names in each project's tech stack.

My challenge is finding an efficient and clean way to associate these technology logos with their respective names and dynamically display them in my React application for each project's description.

I want to avoid hardcoding the image tags for each technology, and instead, find a more scalable and maintainable approach. How can I achieve this in my React application?

When I reference the logo by its import name "reactLogo", it displays an URL to the image, not the image itself. Is there a way to reference it by name and not have to embed it using  each time?

```
import nodejsLogo from './images/nodejs.png';
import reactLogo from './images/reactlogo.png';

function Projects() {

  const projects = [
    {
      title: "Weather App",
      imageSrc: "/weather1.png",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae nulla nec metus interdum euismod. Sed id sapien id arcu eleifend egestas.",
      techStack: [<img src = {nodejsLogo} alt="Node.js" className="project-logo"/>, reactLogo, "Tech 3", "Tech 4"],
    },
   // more projects

  ];

  return (
    <Element name="projects" className="container">
      <section id="projects" className="projects">
        <div>
          <h2>
            My
            <span className=""> Projects </span>
          </h2>
          {projects.map((project, index) => (
            <Project
              key={index}
              title={project.title}
              imageSrc={project.imageSrc}
              description={project.description}
              techStack={project.techStack}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </section>
    </Element>
  );
}

export default Projects;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serve these images yourself, you can do so from the [`public` folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) so you don't have to `import` them manually in your code. However, the code example below can load any URL passed via the `logoSrc` property.

According to the documentation, you should only use it when...

> You have thousands of images and **need to dynamically reference their
> paths**.

Emphasis by me.

Code example:

```js
const projects = [
  {
    title: 'Weather App',
    imageSrc: '%PUBLIC_URL%/img/projects/weather/weather1.png',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...',
    techStack: [
      {
        name: 'React',
        logoSrc: '%PUBLIC_URL%/img/tech/react/logo.svg',
      },
      {
        name: 'NodeJS',
        logoSrc: '%PUBLIC_URL%/img/tech/nodejs/logo.svg',
      },
    ],
  },
  // more projects
];

export function Projects() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        My
        <span className=""> Projects </span>
      </h2>
      {projects.map(({ title, techStack }) => (
        <>
          <div>{title}</div>
          <div>
            <div>Technology Stack:</div>
            {techStack.map(({ name, logoSrc }) => (
              <>
                <span>{name}</span>
                <img
                  className={'project-logo'}
                  src={logoSrc}
                  alt={`${name} logo`}
                />
              </>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```